# IDE says MasterPage not found, but builds/runs fine

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I am stumped as to why my pages are saying the MasterPage cannot be found, even though the MasterPages are where they are specified. For example:

In default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Welcome" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="My_site.default" %>
```

In the above line, `"~/Master.Master"` is underlined in green. Hovering with my mouse shows a balloon that reads `File '~/Master.Master' was not found.` Master.Master definitely exists in the root folder of my site. The site builds fine and all of my pages DO find  ~/Master.Master when ran on either my local PC or when uploaded to my hosting account.

The biggest annoyance is that I can't view my pages in the VS IDE because it says `The Master Page file '~/Master.Master' cannot be loaded. Correct the problem in Code view.` I see nothing to fix...

I have completely deleted the /obj/Debug and /obj/Development folders, clicked to Clean the entire solution, and done a complete build. Every page that uses a Master Page on my site is telling me this.

After running into some problems with long filename errors (unrelated issue) I moved my solution/project to a folder off of my C:. I named the solution folder C:\My_Site and inside of it there is a project folder called My_Site. The full path to my project files is C:\My_site\My_Site.

If I change `MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master"` to `MasterPageFile="~/My_Site/My_Site/Master.Master"` then the IDE stops reporting an error and will allow me to view pages in design mode without a problem - although the site will not build this way. The compiler reports problems that the Master Pages cannot be found.

I read a post here on SO - [Error: "The file '/MasterPages/MainMaster.master' does not exist." (Yes, this file does exist!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825498/error-the-file-masterpages-mainmaster-master-does-not-exist-yes-this-fi) but my files are not located in a virtual folder. I use IIS Express and so am pretty limited with configuring it. I am uneasy about right-clicking my project and converting it to anything. I'm not sure what the effect of that would be.

Anyone have an idea what's possibly happening and how I might resolve this?